# I think that this question is not off-topic

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions, close-reasons

The following question has been closed because it is off-topic:

[An approximation for path integral kernels](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/626109/)

However, I'm presenting a new idea in that post: Set N=2 in the formula of the path integral kernel and derive an approximation for the kernel. This question is definitely not a homework and I'm not asking anyone to check the derivation. I have checked numerically that the derivation is correct.

Comment: I don't see any actual question in that post. What are you asking if not for us to check the derivation?

Comment: I'm just asking an opinion on the method.

Comment: In that case HW-like may be the wrong closure reason, but it would be equally off-topic as either opinion-based or [bordering on peer-review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/50583).

Comment: *I'm just asking an opinion on the method.* Opinion-based questions are *off-topic*. However, I am a bit skeptical of your claim that $N=2$ gives a good approximation to the $N\to\infty$ result. It seems surprising to me. Perhaps it works well for some potentials but not others? I think an on-topic question might be “Why does this extremely crude approximation work so well?” in some particular case.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to Physics!

In its current form (v4) it’s unclear to me what your post is asking about. One symptom: it does not appear to contain a question that ends in a question mark.

Your self-answer suggests that you have solved the problem you were having by locating a factor of two. That’s typical of check-my-work questions, which our community has decided are off-topic.

If you are hoping to have a freewheeling discussion about a new idea, Physics.SE isn’t a good venue: we’re a question-and-answer community.