# Is critique of mainstream interpretation of experimental results allowed?

Tags: discussion

As we all know, scientific data must be gathered, processed and interpreted. Now, there is a somewhat old Nature article reporting on an experiment conducted by the authors, actually a replication of other published experiments, in order to test a null-hypothesis. They conduct a statistical analysis and acknowledge that the experimental results violate the null-hypothesis. Still they conclude that the null-hypothesis holds, but that there is an unknown variation source messing it up.

The topic straddles different scientific disciplines, but at its core it can be cast as a physical problem. Would a question about this article and its arguments be allowed on this site? I fear not, but I have trouble figuring out a rational argument why it should not, so I would appreciate an explanatory answer.

Comment: What *sort* of question? Your title asks about a "critique" but the body of your question doesn't ever get specific. For instance, if your question essentially amounts to "Is this article correct?" or "I think this articles is wrong and here's why, do you agree?", then this is [off-topic as a request for peer review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/50583).

Comment: ,@ACuriousMind Thanks for your prompt reply. The link you provided pretty much settles it.